# Javascript - How can I send the value of the text area to my textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to send the value of the text area to the textbox. the text area value is get from the qr-code once it is scanned. so i want to send the textarea value to the textbox value

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['btnSubcode'])) {
      $lblCode  =  isset($_POST['lblQrTxt']) ? $_POST['lblQrTxt'] : '';

      $code = $lblCode;
      $code = explode(":",$code); // code = array("QR Code","444444444|123")
      $code = explode("|",$code[1]); // code[1] = "444444444|123"
      $code = trim($code[0]); // 444444444

      $code2 = $lblCode;
      $code2 = explode(":",$code2); // code = array("QR Code","444444444|123")
      $code2 = explode("|",$code2[1]); // code[1] = "444444444|123"
      $code2 = trim($code2[1]); // 123
 }
 ?>

 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label">code</label>
      <input type="text" id="card-code" value='<?php echo $code ?>' class="form-control">
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="form-control-label">pin</label>
           <input type="text" id="card-pin" value='<?php echo $code2 ?>' class="form-control" maxlength="3">
      </div>
 </div>
 </form>

///////////////////////////////THIS IS THE TEXT AREA///////////////////////
         <textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea><br><br>
                               <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="btnSubcode"></input>
```

there is my code, so the value comes in the textarea. so when the value is set i want an automatic transfer on the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need something like this:

```js
$('#scanned-QR').on('change textInput input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    $("input[name=input]").val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control text-center" id="scanned-QR" name="lblQrTxt"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="text" name = "input"></input>
```

Comment: hey sir this is helpful but can you please remove the button? because i dont need the button, can you please remove it thanks

Comment: @obitouchiha So you need to change it everytime the textarea changes?

Comment: yes sir that is what i need :( can you please help me thanks

Comment: @obitouchiha like that?

Comment: hi sir when the code popped up , the value is not inserted into the textbox automatically. :( even i click nothing was beign send :(

Comment: @obitouchiha Have you tried losing the focus on textarea?

Comment: not yet can you show me i dont know losing the focus

Comment: @obitouchiha Losing the focus means clicking on any white space around the elements after you wrote something in textarea.

Comment: oh yeah i tried that and it work but in my case that is not what i need sir, cant it be done without clicking anything after i type?

Comment: or lets change it lets just do a paragraph then it will copy on the textbox can it be done like that??

Comment: can it be done with a paragraph only and it will copy the value and send it to the textbox?

Comment: @obitouchiha Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.

```
$("#idOfTextBox").val($("#idOfTextArea").val())
```

if you want to use javascript, then

```
document.getElementById("idOfTextBox').value = 
document.getElementById("idOfTextArea').value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        function changeBack(){
          document.getElementById("card-pin").value = document.getElementById("scanned-QR").value;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
          <textarea name="myTextArea" rows=2 cols=50 onChange='changeBack()'>
          Here is some text in my text area.
          </textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```